# How do I change my OWA server's URL?

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-web-app

I need to change the URL that my OWA server uses from https://owa.domain.com to https://mail.newdomain.com.

Can I change the URL even though the server still resides in the original domain.com Active Directory domain?

It appears that I can just go into Exchange Console -> Server Configuration -> Client Access and update all of the properties for OWA, OAB and ActiveSync with the new domain.  Replace my SSL cert and I'm good to go.

But is it really that easy?

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a redirect to the new address using IIS.

> Windows Server 2008    For a
>   Configuration in Which SSL Is Not
>   Required on the Default Web Site or on
>   the OWA Virtual Directory in IIS 7.0
>
> To use IIS Manager to simplify the
>   Outlook Web Access URL Start the
>   Internet Information Services (IIS)
>   Manager snap-in.
>
> Expand the local computer, expand
>   Sites, and then click Default Web
>   Site.
>
> At the bottom of the Default Web Site
>   Home pane, click Features View if this
>   option is not already selected.
>
> In the IIS section, double-click HTTP
>   Redirect.
>
> Click to select the Redirect requests
>   to this destination check box, and
>   then type /owa.
>
> Under Redirect Behavior, click to
>   select the Only redirect requests to
>   content in this directory (not
>   subdirectories) check box.
>
> In the Status code list, click Found
>   (302).
>
> In the Actions pane, click Apply.
>
> For the new settings to take effect,
>   start a command prompt, and then run
>   the IISReset command.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998359%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

You can also modify the properties of the virtual directory, but I'm not sure of all the consequences of that.

> To use the Exchange Management Console
>   to modify the properties on an Outlook
>   Web Access virtual directory In the
>   Exchange Management Console, locate
>   the virtual directory that you want to
>   modify by using the information in
>   step 2 or step 3.
>
> If you are running the Mailbox server
>   role on the computer that is running
>   the Client Access server role, do one
>   of the following:
>
> To modify an Exchange 2007 virtual
>   directory, select Server
>   Configuration, select Client Access,
>   and then click the Outlook Web Access
>   tab. The default Exchange 2007 virtual
>   directory is /owa. To modify a legacy
>   virtual directory, select Server
>   Configuration, select Mailbox, and
>   then click the WebDAV tab. The default
>   legacy virtual directories are as
>   follows: /Public, /Exchweb, /Exchange,
>   and /Exadmin. If you are not running
>   the Mailbox server role on the
>   computer that is running the Client
>   Access server role, select Server
>   Configuration, select Client Access,
>   and then click the Outlook Web Access
>   tab.
>
> In the work pane, select the virtual
>   directory that you want to modify, and
>   then click Properties.
>
> In the virtual directory properties
>   dialog box, select the tab that
>   contains the properties that you want
>   to modify.
>
> Make the changes that you want.
>
> Click OK to save your changes and
>   close the properties window.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123882%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

Obviously, read up and apply what fits for your given situation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can safely do that: Exchange web URLs (as well as SMTP domains) don't have any forced relationship to the internal Active Directory domain name, and you can change them as needed.

You have to change the URLs in the Exchange Management Console (or Shell), and of course you will need a new certificate with the right name(s); you will also need to configure you external DNS, firewall, reverse proxy (if any), etc.; but as long as all the supporting infrastructure is configured properly, you can set Exchange's URLs to anything you like.